# How to differentiate sources with HealthKit sleep query

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm currently using the following code to query for the number of hours the user was asleep in the last 24 hours:

```
   func getHealthKitSleep() {
        let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

        // Get all samples from the last 24 hours
        let endDate = Date()
        let startDate = endDate.addingTimeInterval(-1.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0)
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: [])

        // Sleep query
        let sleepQuery = HKSampleQuery(
            sampleType: HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!,
            predicate: predicate,
            limit: 0,
            sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]){ (query, results, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {return}
                // Sum the sleep time
                var minutesSleepAggr = 0.0
                if let result = results {
                    for item in result {
                        if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                            if sample.value == HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.asleep.rawValue && sample.startDate >= startDate {
                                let sleepTime = sample.endDate.timeIntervalSince(sample.startDate)
                                let minutesInAnHour = 60.0
                                let minutesBetweenDates = sleepTime / minutesInAnHour
                                minutesSleepAggr += minutesBetweenDates
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.sleep = Double(String(format: "%.1f", minutesSleepAggr / 60))!
                    print("HOURS: \(String(describing: self.sleep))")
                }
        }
        // Execute our query
        healthStore.execute(sleepQuery)
    }
```

This works great if the user has only one sleep app as the source for the data. The problem is if the user is using 2 sleep apps, for example, as sources, the data will be doubled. How can I differentiate the sources? If able to differentiate the sources, I would like to either only grab data from one source, or maybe take the average of the sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're looping over the samples, you can access information about the source for each. I only accept a single source, so I just keep a variable of the source name and if the current sample has a different source name I continue looping without processing the data from that sample, but you could combine the data in other ways if you wanted to.

Here's how to access the source info:

```
if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
    let name = sample.sourceRevision.source.name
    let id = sample.sourceRevision.source.bundleIdentifier
}
```

There's some more info on the `HKSourceRevision` object [in the docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksourcerevision).